# Exchange: Set ProhibitSendReceiveQuota on Objects

Tags: variables, loops, powershell, exchange-server

I want to set all exchange users ProhibitSendReceiveQuota to UNLIMITED.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox
foreach($m in $mailbox){
    Set-Mailbox -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -UNLIMITED
}
```

But it is asking for an identity when I run this.

Any ideas?

I would also like to loop through when I am finished, and output any user that has ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -gt 1MB

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipeline the malibox identity directly from get-mailbox to set-mailbox:

```
Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota UNLIMITED
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not telling **Set-Mailbox** which mailboxes to modify. You're running the command inside a **Foreach-Object** loop that sets **$m** to each mailbox, but you're not using **$m** inside the loop (which defeats the purpose of a **Foreach-Object** loop).

The bottom line is that **-Identity** is a required parameter for the **Set-Mailbox** command, and you're not specifying it -- which is why you're being prompted. Change your command to this:

```powershell
Set-Mailbox $m -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota unlimited
```

- **-Identity** is implied, because it's the first positional parameter.
- Note the lack of a `-` before `unlimited`, which would make PowerShell parse it as a separate (and nonexistent) parameter instead of an argument for `-ProhibitSendReceiveQuota`.

There are a number of attributes that can be used as an argument to the **-Identity** parameter. Take a look at the documentation for this parameter, which has a list of valid identity attributes (note also the `Required?     true`):

```
-Identity <MailboxIdParameter>
  The Identity parameter specifies the mailbox. You can use the following values:
  * ADObjectID
  * Alias
  * Distinguished name (DN)
  * Domain\Account
  * GUID
  * LegacyExchangeDN
  * SmtpAddress
  * User principal name (UPN)

  Required?                    true
  Position?                    1
  Default value
  Accept pipeline input?       True
  Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

However, this list is incomplete. Oddly enough, the **Identity** attribute isn't included, but it's certainly valid. **Name** and **DisplayName** also work. And, of course, you can just provide a mailbox object as the identity argument, as in my command above (that works because the default attribute for mailbox object is **DisplayName**).

So, `Set-Mailbox $_.Identity [...]`, `Set-Mailbox $_.DistinguishedName [...]`, etc. would all work just as well. That's mainly useful if you're invoking the cmdlet in a loop or pipeline that's already narrowed down to a specific mailbox attribute.

The pipeline in mjolinor's answer works because as you can see in the documentation, the **-Identity** parameter takes pipeline input, so each object in the result set of **Get-Mailbox** is provided as the **-Identity** argument. Note also that a pipeline is more efficient for large data sets.

Speaking of large data sets, be aware that by default, **Get-Mailbox** only returns the first 1,000 results. So unless you have a small organization with fewer than 1,000 mailboxes, you want to do this:

```powershell
foreach ($m in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited) {
    Set-Mailbox -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota unlimited
}
```

or the pipeline version

```powershell
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Set-Mailbox -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually think if you want to do this for your entire organization the best practice method would be to run this with the `Get-MailboxDatabase | Set-MailboxDatabase -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota` command instead of get-mailbox. Putting the quotas on the database creates a default and then you can override by setting it on the Mailbox object instead. I think it's just a best-practice option. This would also likely be executed faster.